# Loop : if element exist click on it else contenue to the next step on Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

im trying to delete all product from cart. So i search for a loop who : if element exist i click on this element else this element doest more exist. So if not exist i can go to the next step. I write this code but not working :

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
             EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')))
        if len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')) > 0:
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]').click()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to handle the exception instead?

```py
try:
   WebDriverWait(self.driver, 30).until(
             EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')))
except ElementNotFoundException:
   self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use try..except block. it will check if elements present then iterate and click else go except block and then continue.

```
while True:
    try:
        elements=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')))
        for element in elements:
             element.click()
    except:
        print("no more products available")
        break
```

#next step

---

I think you will be always able to click one element and then page will refreshed. so use this code block.

```
while True:
    try:
        elements=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')))
        elements[0].click()        
    except:
        print("no more products available")
        break
```

Comment: it delete just the first one

Comment: after delete the page update cart page

Comment: @FlutterLover : then make infinite loop and check if it works.

Comment: not working : it click in just one and it go to the next step

Comment: I have added a time sleep to wait the page charge after deleting the element :
`        while True:
            try:
                elements = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
                    EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')))
                elements[0].click()
                time.sleep(10)
            except:
                print("no more products available")
                break`